# Lookup different customer ID across multiple tables using different fields

Tags: mysql, database, join, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a lookup column between a new table with purchase data and my historical database, whose primary ID for each customer is different.
The main issue is that some customers do not have an email address in the historical databases, but they always have one in our new system.
The language is mySQL

Here are the tables :

For the new database - let's call it new_data

[image]

For the old database - let's call it old_data

[image]

And What I am trying to get (sorry I forgot to format the Date)

[image]

I tried two approaches:

1. Doing a join two times, first on the email field and then on the name. The main issue is, I am getting a ton of duplicated values even if I put distinct.

```
select distinct * 
from new_data as n
left join old_data as c
on c.email = n.email
left join old_data as d 
on  d.name= n.c_name
```

2. Doing a join across multiple fields with a conditional, and I am getting a lot more rows returned

```
select distinct * from 
new_data n
left join old_data c
on c.email = n.email or  c.name= n.name
```

Comment: I see strict `Name` matching - why you try to join by `email` additionally? Maybe your sample data is not adequate? expand it... and show it as formatted text, not as a picture.

Comment: Because some people might have the same name in my database so I would like to cross check emails first. About 10% of the sample data is missing emails in the old database.

Comment: If so then replace data sample and post representative sample. It must show ALL possible combinations which must be taken into account during the query creation.

Comment: Does `email` column is defined as UNIQUE? Does it cannot contain duplicates? Does it is possible that the name for the same email differs in old and new tables?

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron. For further help, see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: not sure why this question got closed; it does state everything needed to answer the question

Comment: I know, not sure why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join first on the email field, and if that is not found, then on the name, just do that:

```
select n.id new_id, email.id old_id_by_email, name.id old_id_by_name
from new_data n
left join old_data email on email.email=n.email
left join old_data name on email.id is null and name.name=n.name
```

If you are getting more than one row for each new_id, you should think about what you want (lowest old id?  ordered by some date?).

To set the old ids,

```
update new_data n
left join old_data email on email.email=n.email
left join old_data name on email.id is null and name.name=n.name
set n.old_id=coalesce(email.id,name.id)
where n.old_id is null;
```

or just use two updates:

```
update new_data
join old_data on old_data.email=new_data.email
set new_data.old_id=old_data.id
where new_data.old_id is null;

update new_data
join old_data on old_data.name=new_data.name
set new_data.old_id=old_data.id
where new_data.old_id is null;
```

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to use distinct for, but presuming each table has a primary key, `distinct *` is never going to remove any rows, since there will always be some difference; perhaps you wanted to be using `group by` somehow?

The above updates assume mysql; for snowflake, I don't see immediately how to use left joins, but you can do two updates like (untested):

```
update new_data
set new_data.old_id=old_data.id
from old_data 
where new_data.old_id is null and old_data.email=new_data.email;

update new_data
set new_data.old_id=old_data.id
from old_data 
where new_data.old_id is null and old_data.name=new_data.name;
```

Comment: I was trying to remove the duplicate rows by using distinct. Thank you for the answers. i understood the first query block, but I am not sure about the update. When I run the update query it gave me an error saying unexpected join. Do I need to add any from at all/select? sorry I am not familiar with the update statement

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'left'. I am using Snowflake, which runs the same as mySQL

Comment: snowflake is not mysql and does not have the same syntax.  I will add to my answer